# 140W CPU on AMD780?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I've got the M3A78-EM mobo (http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=KjpYqzmAd9vsTM2D&content=specifications), based on the 780G chipset, that claims to support 140W CPUs (like Phenom II).

However, I read many accounts of people trying to plug a 125W or 140W CPU into a 780G-based mobo, and frying the mobo seconds after boot-up.

I wonder if anyone has successfully done this with this particular board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU power (wattage) that a motherboard can support is a function of the DC-DC regulator design and layout of the motherboard and has nothing to do with what type of chipset is on the motherboard. If the motherboard specs support 140W CPUs, then you're good as long as you have adequate cooling.

Answer (score 2):

This CPU is only supported on Rev. 1.03G and newer PCB of this mobo. What revision do you have?

[link](http://forums.ncix.com/forums/index.php?mode=showthread&msg_id=2019074&threadid=2019074&forum=101&product_id=39335&msgcount=4&overclockid=0)

Answer (score 2):

the only Phenom which uses the 140W is the X4 965,which is the latest from AMD

unless you plan on buying that CPU,you're safe,i guess